# From a Python venv, find installation from which the venv command was run

Tags: python, python-venv

Given a Python virtual environment created with `pythonXY_EXE -m venv venv`,
how do I find the python executable PythonYX_EXE used to create the virtual environment?

Solutions for both MS-Windows and Linux are sought.

For Linux, I can come up with a solution by resolving the symlink with `readlink -f venv/bin/python`.
But for MS Windows?

A non-answer is the official [Creation of virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html):

> ... pyvenv.cfg file in it with a home key pointing to the Python installation from which the command was run

My goal: Running python without copy/symlink, as those may fork multiple processes.

Comment: I don't have a Windows machine, but what does `venv/bin/python --version` returns?

Comment: On Windows, `venv/Scripts/python --version ` gives `Python 3.8.6`

Comment: Believe this is a symlink, so perhaps this might help? The `dir` command might expose the symlink metadata: https://superuser.com/questions/524669/checking-where-a-symbolic-link-points-at-in-windows-7

Comment: Afaik on Windows it is some kind of copy, not a symlink. The `dir /a` does not work for me on Windows 10, it shows `python.exe`as regular file.

Answer (score 0):

On MS Windows, by inspecting the [source code of the venv library](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/venv/__init__.py), the executable is located at (if symlinks are not enabled or failed)

```
<home-key-of-pyvenv.cfg-file>/python.exe.
```